# Problems with JQuery and the ScrollTo() function

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#home_slider" id="home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#portfolio_slider" id="portfolio">Potfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact_slider" id="contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

and I want to use ScrollTo() to go to the parts when clicked. Im having trouble with the JQuery, so far I have:

```
$("#menu a").click(function(event) {
$("#menu a").removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
$('.sliders').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'));      
 //cancel the link default behavior
 return false;        
});
```

I don't want the screen to move, I just want the .sliders div to horizontally scroll to the correct slider.

Check more code out here: http://www.rickdonohoe.co.uk.

Also the page footer is very far down the page as one of the sliders is very long in length. How could I fix that to make it more dynamic? Maybe stick to the bottom of the page?

Thanks for the help,

Rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is animate the `left` or `margin-left` property of the `.sliders` element. `scrollTo` is for elements with scrollbars, so you would call it on the parent element of the `.sliders` element.

```
$("#menu a").click(function(event) {
    $("#menu a").removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.sliders').animate({left : ($($(this).attr('href')).position().left * -1)}, 500);      
    //cancel the link default behavior
    return false;        
});
```

`($($(this).attr('href')).position().left * -1)`: this bit of code selects the clicked link's href value, gets it's relative position to it's parent element and multiplies it by negative one so the animation will go the correct direction.

### Update

You can fix your footer to the bottom of the `viewport` using this CSS:

```
#footer {
    position   : fixed;
    bottom     : 0;
    left       : 0;
    right      : 0;
    background : #fff;
}
```

### Update

Also if you add this bit of JavaScript you can dynamically set the height of the document so it doesn't have a bunch of white space: `.parent().height($($(this).attr('href')).height());`

```
$("#menu a").click(function(event) {
    $("#menu a").removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.sliders').animate({left : ($($(this).attr('href')).position().left * -1)}, 500).parent().height($($(this).attr('href')).height());      
    //cancel the link default behavior
    return false;        
});
```

Comment: Great Stuff! Only problem now is why the first panel has been cut short mid paragraph by the footer.... Any ideas?!

Answer (score 1):

Remember to always check the documentation!

http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

```
scrollTop()
    .scrollTop() 
scrollTop( value  )
    .scrollTop( value )
```

It doesn't accept a jquery or html element. It can get **or** set a value.

You will need to use:

http://api.jquery.com/position/

```
**Description:** Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set
of matched elements, relative to the offset parent.
```

Also considder using a descendant selector:
    $($this, ".selected")

To animate you can use jQuery animate:

```
[http://api.jquery.com/animate/][3]
```